# How to get list of weekdays from Mon to Sun momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to get list of weekdays from Monday to Sunday.
Relaying on docs there is a method returns a list of weekdays

```
moment.weekdays()
```

but it returns a list of weekdays from Sunday to Saturday

I've already updated moment locale

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    week: { dow: 1 },
});
```

Comment: Have you loaded the locales library too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `true` to your weekdays function, e.g.

`moment.weekdays(true)`

along with keeping the locale code

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/